# Sortable, draggable and cloning list

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, clone, draggable, sortables

1) I have two sortable list. The first list clone to second the elements.

2) Example: I clone "item 1" 5 times to list 2. Then I drag from list 2, the 5 "item 1" to list 1.

3) Now in list 1 I have six "items 1" and I want only one, **the original**.

Is possible that?

http://jsfiddle.net/fekula/v265q/195/

Thank you.

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        remove: function(event, ui) {
            ui.item.clone().appendTo('#sortable2');
            $(this).sortable('cancel');
        }
    }).disableSelection();

$( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: You could remove the connectWith key in the second sortable function.

Comment: But the items doesn't dissapear from list 2

Comment: Perhaps it's best if you connect the second one with a trash bin.

Comment: I should say that I appreciate how difficult this problem actually is.  I tried attaching a function to the sortable's `out` event, but it triggers during sorting as well as dragging outside of the sortable: http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/v265q/196/